# Show that $\forall (x,y)$ in the first quadrant: $\frac {x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$

Tags: inequality, multivariable-calculus

I have the folowing exercise (which I've been thinking quite a while and couldn't figure out):

Show that $\forall (x,y)$ in the first quadrant:
$$\frac {x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$$

My idea was to work with maxima and minima, but I'm stuck...
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Does it help to denote $$ f(x,y)=e^{x+y-2}-\frac {x^2+y^2}{4}$$ and then find the minima of the function in the first quadrant by following the multivariable tools? It seems to me the natural way to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Essentially the same idea as in the previous  answers, just put slightly differently:)*

For $x, y \ge 0$
$$
 \frac {x^2+y^2}{4} \le \frac {(x+y)^2}{4} = \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right)^2 \, ,
$$
therefore it suffices to show that
$$
\left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right)^2 \le e^{x+y-2} \Longleftrightarrow 
\frac{x+y}{2} \le e^{\frac{x+y}{2}-1} \, .
$$
The latter is true because 
$$
 1 + u \le e^{u} 
$$
holds for all real numbers $u$ (the right-hand side is a convex function and
therefore its graph lies above the tangent line at $u=0$, 
see also [Simplest or nicest proof that $1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex)).

Comment: I think it comes out to $eu \le e^u$. Were you implying that it's very easy to prove this from $1 + u \le e^{u}$?

Comment: @Ovi: With the substitution  $u= \frac{x+y}{2}-1$ the last inequality becomes $u+1 \le e^u$.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you

Comment: That is so cool/weird that you can go back and forth between an additive inequality, $1+x \le e^x$ and $ex \le e^{x-1}$. I hope I will remember this trick and be able to use it in other cases. Is this an important trick that you keep in mind, or come from a more general method, or is it just a cute little thing?

Comment: @Ovi:  Going from additive (in)equalities to multiplicative (in)equalities and vice versa, via  $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$ or $\log (xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$, is surely something that you should keep in mind.

Comment: To go from $1+x \le e^x$ to $ey \le e^{y-1}$ we use $x =y-1$. Could you please clarify how you would use $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$ to switch between additive and multiplicative? I of course see addition on one side and multiplication on the other, but I don't see how it would be used in the same way that we used $x =y-1$.

Comment: @Ovi: It uses $e^{y-1} = e^y / e^1$ ...

Comment: Yes, I just thought you meant there was something more to it than that. Thanks for  all the help!

Answer (score 9):

Look at this on a given circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.. for which $\theta$ is the right-hand side smallest? This will reduce it to a problem involving only one variable.

Comment: Could you explain a bit better? I'm almost there....

Comment: write $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$. The left hand side is ${r^2 \over 4}$, and the right hand side is a function of $r$ and $\theta$. Minimize the right-hand side in $\theta$, and now you have a 1-dimensional problem (which still requires some work)

Answer (score 3):

Taking @Zarrax's suggestion, you will find that the minimum value of the exponent is $r-2$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  Taking logs of both sides, you get $2 \log{(r/2)}$ for the LHS and $r-2$ for the RHS.  Now apply the inequality $\log{x} \le x-1 \: \forall \, x>0$ where $x=r/2$, and the inequality follows.