# Showing that $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and not having much success.  I'm attempting to use a modified version of the following result (which I found on Math Stack Exchange here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172988/please-prove-uniform-continuity
), that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ and the limit of $f(x)=L$ as $x$ approaches infinity, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$.

This is the work I've done so far.  I really don't know if it's valid reasoning...
The first problem I'm encountering is that the book has not yet defined functional limits, so I can't really use the proof directly.  We have, however defined sequential limits and the notion of a decreasing function.  If I define a sequence $x_n=n-1$ for $n$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$, then as $n$ goes to infinity, $f(x_n)\rightarrow0$.  For $\epsilon/2$, $\exists$N$\in$$\mathbb{N}$ s.th for all n $\geq$ N,  |$f(x_n)|$ <$\epsilon/2$. Then, since $f(x)$ is a decreasing function, this inequality holds for all $x$$\geq$$x_N$. 
Since $\mathcal{S}$=$[0,N+1]$ is closed and bounded, and hence a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$, and $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is continuous on $\mathcal{S}$, then by the Uniform Continuity Theorem, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathcal{S}$.

So, if $x,y$ $\in$$\mathcal{S}$,$\forall$$\epsilon>0,$ $\exists$ $\delta>0$ s.th |$x-y$|<$\delta$ then |$f(x)-f(y)$|<$\epsilon$.  Then (really not sure about this part), if $x, y$ $\in$$(N+1,\infty)$, for any $x$ and $y$ in this set, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)+(-f(y))|$$\leq|f(x)|+|f(y)|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$.  So $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(N+1,\infty)$.  Provided this part is correct, I am having trouble with the case where $x$$\in[0,N+1]$ and $y$ $\in(N+1,\infty)$.  Provided it's not correct, I'm having trouble on that part as well.  Provided none of this is correct, well... I don't know.

Any help would be appreciated.  Is this an appropriate way to approach the problem?  Are there other ways?

Comment: Forget about limits. What can you say about the set of values of the derivative $f'(x) = - e^{-x}$ for $x \in [0,+\infty)$?

Comment: We have not yet defined the derivative.  We're using Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Proof 1**

$f'(x)$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$: $|f'(x)|\leq M $ for some $M\geq0$

Lagrange mean value theorem

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M |x-y|$$

$f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

**Proof 2**

If you want to use the fact that the limit of $f(x)=L$ as x approaches infinity, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$

1). $\lim f(x)=L $,  so, $\forall \epsilon \gt0$, there is $T \gt 0$ such that

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\lt \epsilon  \qquad x,y\gt T$$

2). $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,T+1]$, that is, there is $\delta_1 \gt 0$ such that $x,y\in [0,T+1] ,|x-y|\lt \delta_1$

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\lt \epsilon $$

3). Let $\delta=\min\{1,\delta_1\}$. If $x,y\geq0, |x-y|\lt \delta $, then $x,y\in [T,\infty) $ or $x,y\in [0,T+1]$. From 1) and 2), we have

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\lt \epsilon $$

so $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: This is good.  I like proof 2.  I'll keep proof 1 in mind for future use once we've defined the derivative.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

For any $x>0$ and $y>0$ we have
$$
    \left\vert \mathrm{e}^{-x} - \mathrm{e}^{-y} \right\vert = \left\vert \mathrm{e}^{-\min(x,y)} \left(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-|y-x|}\right) \right\vert = \mathrm{e}^{-\min(x,y)} \left(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-|y-x|}\right) \leqslant \mathrm{e}^{-\min(x,y)} |y-x| 
$$
Hence for all $x>0, y>0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$
$$
    \left\vert \mathrm{e}^{-x} - \mathrm{e}^{-y} \right\vert < \delta
$$
which verifies the direct [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Definition_for_functions_on_metric_spaces) of uniform continuity.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Is the argument wrong? not what the OP is asking?

Comment: I like the trick with $\max(x,y)$ :), so I upvoted.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache Thanks for your vote.

Comment: To just expand Sasha's answer, recall that $$\max(x,y) = \frac{x +y  + |x - y|}{2}$$

Comment: @Sasha I don't understand the first equality. If I substitute in the formula given by Nameless, it doesn't work out. Can you please explain?

Comment: @user137090 Consider first the case of $x<y$. Then $\exp(-x) - \exp(-y) = \exp(-x) \left(1-\exp(-(y-x)\right)$. Now consider $y<x$. By the way, I had an error in the formula. It should be $\min$, instead of $\max$.

Comment: @user137090 More formally:$$ | \exp(-x) - \exp(-y) | = | \exp(-\max(x,y)) - \exp(-\min(x,y)) | = \exp(-\min(x,y)) | 1 - \exp(-\left(\max(x,y)-\min(x,y)\right)) | = \exp(-\min(x,y)) | 1 - \exp(-|y-x|) |$$

Comment: Hello there. I don’t understand why does $1-e^{-|y-x|}\leq |y-x|$

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/504671/11069