# Is function $ f(x)= e^{-(x+x^{2})} $ uniformly continuous on $R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Is function $ f(x)= e^{-( x+ x^{2}) } $ uniformly continuous on $ R $?

---

As we know for any function $f$ which is continuous on $R$ and $ \lim_{ x\to  \infty} f(x)  $ ,  $ \lim_{x \to - \infty } f(x) $ exist finitely, then $ f$ is uniformly continuous.

---

I am confused about the limit of $f$ at $ - \infty $.

Please help.

Comment: Hint: Complete the square

Comment: after that you may try using the arguments in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/769007/290189 to complete your proof

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=-(x^2+x)=-(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{x \to -\infty}g(x)=-\infty$

$\lim_{x \to -\infty}g(x)=-\infty$   $\Rightarrow$  $\lim_{x \to -\infty}e^{g(x)}=0$