# proof for $n(1-\frac{k+1}{n})^{n\ln(k+1)/(k+1)}<ne^{-\ln(k+1)}$

Tags: calculus, graph-theory, logarithms

I came across this inequality in a graph theory book, couldn't figure how to prove it.

$$n\left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)^{n\ln(k+1)/(k+1)}<ne^{-\ln(k+1)}.$$

$n$ and $k$ are both positive integers. (Amount of vertices and minimum degree if that matters.)

Comment: Are you familiar with the inequality $(1 + \tfrac1x)^{x} < e$?

Comment: No but if the proof involves it I would gladly learn it.

Comment: Correction: that inequality holds for positive $x$, and the reverse inequality for negative $x$. Now apply the inequality to $-n/(k+1)$... do you see how to go form there?

Comment: hmmmm no sorry...

Comment: Are you familiar with the inequality $1+x \leq e^x$? This is true for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and the equality holds if and only if $x = 0$. Geometrically, this follows from the fact that $e^x$ is strictly convex and $y=x+1$ is the tangent line at $x = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the well know inequality $\log(1+x)<x$ for $x\neq 0$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1466004), [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891128)), we get
\begin{align}
\ln\left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)&<-\frac{k+1}n\\
\frac n{k+1}\ln\left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)&<-1\\
\frac{n\ln(k+1)}{k+1}\ln\left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)&<-\ln(k+1)\\
\ln\left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)^{n\ln(k+1)/(k+1)}&<-\ln(k+1)\\
\left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)^{n\ln(k+1)/(k+1)}&<e^{-\ln(k+1)}\\
n\left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)^{n\ln(k+1)/(k+1)}&<ne^{-\ln(k+1)}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please explain how you derived the 4th line from the 3rd? is there some rule that if $$ab < c$$ then $$b^a < c$$? seems not right, so probably something else?

Comment: $a\ln (b)=\ln (b^a) $

Comment: oh right, thank you!