# Prove that $\frac{1}{^n\sqrt{1+m}}+\frac{1}{^m\sqrt{1+n}}\geq1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

> Prove that
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}}\geq1\quad\forall m,n\in\Bbb N.$$

I've tried to use a common denominator but only got myself into more square problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**hint**: $\sqrt[n]{1+m} =\sqrt[n]{1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots 1\cdot (1+m)} \leq \dfrac{n-1+1+m}{n}=\dfrac{m+n}{n}$

Comment: Elegant application of AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 6):

In fact,your inequality for any $m,n\in R(>1)$ is hold.

because you can  use Bernoulli inequality
$$(1+x)^a\le 1+ax,0<a<1\Longrightarrow \sqrt[n]{1+m}=(1+m)^{\frac{1}{n}}<1+\frac{m}{n}$$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m+1}}>\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{m}{n}}=\dfrac{n}{m+n}$$