# Proof that $e^x\leq C_n(1+|x|)^n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

It is well known $1+x\leq e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex) for several proofs of it.

I wanted to show for every $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a constant $C_n>0$ such that $$e^x\leq C_n(1+|x|)^n,$$ forall $x\in\mathbb R$.

I did a proof (hope it is right):

If  $x\in (-\infty, 0]$ then $e^x<1\leq (1+|x|)^n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$;

If $x\in (0, 1)$ then $e^x<e\leq e(1+|x|)^n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$;

If $x\geq 1$ then by Taylor's formula there is $c\in [0, x]$ such that:
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle e^x&=|e^x|\\
&=\left| e^x-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}x^j+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}x^j\right|\\
&\leq \left| e^x-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}x^j\right|+\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}x^j\right|\\
&\leq \frac{e^c}{n!}|x|^{n}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}|x|^j\\
&\leq \frac{e^c}{n!}|x|^n+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}|x|^{n}\quad (\textrm{since}\ |x|\geq 1)\\
&\leq \left(\frac{e^c}{n!}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}\right) (1+|x|)^n\\
&=C_n (1+|x|)^n,
\end{align*}
for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

The problem is that $c$ is depending on $x$ (isn't it?) and I'd like that not to happen.

Sketching the graph of the functions it is clear for me one can always find $C_n$ not depending on $x$, but I wasn't able to prove it.

So, is my above proof right? Is there really a dependence on $x$ in my constant $C_n$? Can I take drop this dependence?

Thanks

Comment: Since $e^x$ is continuous, it is bounded for all $x$.  So, what does this tell you?

Comment: Do you mean it is bounded on compact subsets containing $x$, right? The function $x\longmapsto e^x$ is not bounded on $\mathbb R$..

Comment: Yes.  But the order of statement is important here.  Here you first fix $x$ and then for any $n$ find the $C_n$, which depends on $x$.  If you try to do it the other way, you will fail since we can always find a value of $x$ for which $e^x$ exceeds a given $C(1+|x|)^n$ for any $n$ and $C$.

Comment: Agreed, but how do I use your first comment?

Comment: It was a question.  For any $x$, we can find a $C$ such that $C>e^x$.  Of what added value is the term $(1+|x|)^n\ge1$ and the indexing of $C$, which seems superfluous?

Comment: The statement you want to show is false. You can not take $C_n$ independent of $x$.