# Proving an inequality which the solution says "is obvious" but I cant see how

Tags: inequality, negative-binomial

I was going through my Lebesgue Measure and Integration course, and I came across this inequality.
$$ \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}\leq e^{-x} $$
I tried expanding both sides, and got
$$\text{LHS}= 1-x+\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n^2}\frac{x^3}{3!}\cdots $$
and $$ \text{RHS}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}\cdots $$
Now, I noticed that all the terms in the LHS are either equal or bigger than the corresponding terms in RHS but I don't know how to conclude the inequality from this.
Am I missing something extremely simple and obvious here?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend taking the derivative of $(1+x/n)^n - e^x$ after having taken inverses on both sides (be careful if you do take inverses of both sides)

Comment: The inequality is in reverse and holds for non-negative values of $x$ and positive integer values of $n$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Forgot to put in that $x$ is non-negative.

Comment: Sometimes an author might say something is "obvious" merely because it follows immediately from something that the author assumes the reader knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your inequality to be true, we need $n<0$ and $x \ge 0$.  Note that from [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex) we know that $$e^{\frac{x}{n}} \ge \;1+\frac{x}{n}$$ 
Now, as $t^{-n}$ is an increasing function if $n<0$, $t>0$, we exponentiate each side by $-n$ to get $$e^{-x} \ge \bigg{(}1+\frac{x}{n}\bigg{)}^{-n}$$ as desired. Of course, if $n \ge  0$, the inequality signs reverse, for a similar reason. So your inequality is, for example, not true when $n=1$ as stated previously.

Comment: Let me see if there's any restriction..

Comment: @Sum-Meister Okay. I will edit accordingly if so.

Comment: Rearranging the original inequality, we get: $e^x \leq (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$, which is, as we all know, false for all n, since this series is increasing and converges to $e^x$.

Comment: The other direction is true though.

Comment: @Omry The inequality in the OP is true if $n=-1$.

Comment: I was assuming n was natural. If it isn't, then substitute n->-n, and get $e^{-x}$'s series, which is decreasing and converges to it.

Comment: @Omry Well that wasn't stated, so I editted in a proof.

Comment: @Sum-Meister How long is this going to take? Not trying to hurry you on, but it does seem to be taking some time. Just going to ask when.

Answer (score 0):

We can take a logarithm from both sides. Then, we have
$-n \log(1 + \frac{x}{n}) \leq -x \Rightarrow n \log(1 + \frac{x}{n}) \geq x \Rightarrow \log(1 + \frac{x}{n}) \geq \frac{x}{n}$

let $\frac x n = y$. Then, we have

$\log(1+y) \geq y$ and this is not true for any $y$