# Prove $ \frac{1}{x+1} \le \ln(1+\frac{1}{x}) \le \frac{1}{x}$ with usage of the definition of a logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

**Use the *defintion of a logarithmic function*** to prove $$ \frac{1}{x+1} \le \ln(1+\frac{1}{x}) \le \frac{1}{x}$$ for any positive integer x.   ( Using defintion : $e^y=\ln^{-1}y$ )

> Attempt: 
>   Using the definition,  $e^y=\ln^{-1}y$ , 
>   I tried to prove the right hand side of the equality first by $ 1 +\frac{1}{x} \gt \frac{1}{x}$,
>     $\ln(1 +\frac{1}{x})\lt \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow   e^{\ln(\frac{x+1}{x})} \le e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ but I am really stuck and lost on how I should do it so that one of the sides there is ln and the other side is the value and also for the equality to be $\le$ as $ 1 +\frac{1}{x} \gt \frac{1}{x}$  is strictly less than and is not equal.

Comment: @user236182 , that question uses MVT

Comment: @mechanodroid uses integration as a definition .

Comment: There are a lot of linked duplicate questions in the link I gave.

Comment: Now How do you define $e^x$.  or $\ln x?$

Comment: @dormacus I posted a new answer there.

Comment: Let me be clear between $e^x $ and $\ln x$ has to be define first without mentioning the other one. Then WHAT IS YOUR DEFINITION OF $\ln x$ without using $e^x$. Since you use $\ln x$ to define $e^x$. you must give us the definition of $\ln x.$

Comment: For any $x>0$ We have 
$$\frac{x}{x+1} =\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{x+1} \le \int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{t+1} =\color{red}{\ln(x+1 )}=\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{t+1}  \le \int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{1}  = x $$

that is 

$$\frac{x}{x+1} \le \ln(x+1 ) \le   x $$

taking $X=\frac1x$ you get 

$$\frac{1}{X+1} \le \ln(\frac1X+1 ) \le   \frac1X $$

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer using log defined only as the inverse of the exponential : For the second inequality, use the property of the exponential function that for all real y, $$e^y \geq 1+y$$ 
Take log on both sides (here is where the log as inverse of the exponential comes in) and use $y=1/x$ to get the result.

Comment: This answer is more in line with the OP’s question. How is the inequality on exponential proven?

Comment: Two ways for positive y: 1) consider the series expansion of the exponential. All the terms after 1+ y are positive. That gives the inequality. The other way is to note that the exponential as well as 1+y have the same value and the same slope at y=0. However, the slope of 1+y is always 1 while the slope exponential is greater than 1 for any positive y (and keeps increasing).

Comment: Do you know a way without calculus? It seems like an elementary proof should be possible

Comment: One can use the definition of the e as the limit as $y \longrightarrow 0$ of $(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}}$.  e is the supremum over all positive y values of this function  (increasing as y approaches 0 from the right). Since $$(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}} \leq e$$, raising both sides to the power of y gives the inequality.

Comment: @ZachBoyd See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex and linked questions there on the right.