# better way to explain $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} e^ \frac {−1}{|x|} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}  e^\frac{−1}{|x|}$$

I know that if $x$ goes to $0$, that $\frac{-1}{|x|}$ goes to $-\infty$ and thus, the limit goes to $0$.

But, is there a more mathematical way to explain it rather than with words?

Comment: Edited the formatting, want to make sure this is what you meant

Comment: Maybe state it as a continuity property of a composition of $\frac{1}{|x|}$ and $e^x$.

Comment: As a part of basic properties of $e^x$ one learns that $e^x\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Your limit is an easy consequence of that property and the standard limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1/x)=0$. In essence what you have said in words in your post is the correct justification.

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed is via $$ e^{-x} \le \frac1{1+x}$$
which itself follows because [$ 1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex) for all $x\ge 0$. Then

$$0\le e^{-1/|x|} \le  \frac1{1+1/|x|} = \frac{|x|}{|x|+1} \le |x| $$
and $|x|\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, so we can conclude with the "[squeeze rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)".

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition. Take $\varepsilon \in (0 , \infty)$ and distinguish two cases:

- if $\varepsilon \in [1 , \infty)$, then $\log \varepsilon \in [0 , \infty)$ and each $\delta \in (0 , \infty)$ is valid: for all $\varepsilon \in [1 , \infty)$, we have (take some $\delta \in (0 , \infty)$),
  $$
   - \frac{1}{|x|} < \log \varepsilon \quad \Longrightarrow \quad e^{- \frac{1}{|x|}} < \varepsilon
  $$
  for $x \in (- \delta , \delta) \setminus \{0\}$.
- if $\varepsilon \in (0 , 1)$, then take $\delta = - \frac{1}{\log \varepsilon}$: for $x \in (- \delta , \delta) \setminus \{0\}$, we have
  $$
  |x| < - \frac{1}{\log \varepsilon} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad - \frac{1}{|x|} < \log \varepsilon \quad \Longrightarrow \quad e^{- \frac{1}{|x|}} < \varepsilon\mbox{.}
  $$