# Find $p$ such that $f(x) = e^{−\frac1{|x|}}$ is differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

The function $f$ is given by

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{−\frac{1}{|x|}} & \text{if } x \ne 0\\
p & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}.
$$

I have to find out which value of $p$ I need, so that the function is differentiable.

*Left limit:*

so what is the limit 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} -\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}.$$

i know $e^{-1/x}$ limit is $0$ so is the total limit then also $0$?

Probably not because $-\frac1{x^2}$ is also there but how do I do it then?

And can somebody explain me how to make the formulas and stuff look pretty for next times?

Comment: Do you mean $$e^{\frac{-1}{|x|}}$$?

Comment: What you have called the "left limit" isn't.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any choice - $p$ is already fixed by continuity condition, differentiability can't bring a second condition.

Comment: I don't understand what this quantity with $1/x^2$ is. But here is a tutorial on typing maths on this site https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I think the OP is trying to investigate the derivative, not the original function itself.

Comment: In addition, now that you know the limit of $e^{-1/|x|}$ from this previous question, you should accept one of the answers there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955006/better-way-to-explain-lim-limits-x-to-0-e-frac-%E2%88%921x

Answer (score 1):

A differentiable function must be continuous. Since $\lim_{x\to0}e^{-1/|x|}=0$, we get that $p=0$.

But is the function differentiable? Well, with $t=1/x$,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-1/|x|}}{x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}{t}{e^{-t}}=0
$$
and with $t=-1/x$,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{-1/|x|}}{x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}{-t}{e^{-t}}=0
$$