# How can we show that $e^{-2\lambda t}\lambda^2\le\frac1{e^2t^2}$ for all $\lambda,t\ge0$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

How can we show that $$e^{-2\lambda t}\lambda^2\le\frac1{e^2t^2}\tag1$$ for all $\lambda,t\ge0$?

Applying $\ln$ to both sides yields that $(1)$ should be equivalent to $$t\lambda\le e^{t\lambda-1}\tag2.$$ So, if I did no mistake, it should suffice to show $x\le e^{x-1}$ for all $x\ge0$. How can we do this?

Comment: The substitution $u=x-1$ transforms  $x \le e^{x-1}$ into $u+1 \le e^u$, which is answered in the above-mentioned Q&A.

Comment: Note that applying the *square root* to (1) gives (2), not an application of the logarithm.

Comment: @MartinR Both is legitimate. I've applied the logarithm, rearranged and then the exponential again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line $y=x$ is tangent on $y=e^{x-1}$ in $x=1$ and since $e^{x-1}$ is convex, then it lies upper that any tangent of it, specially $x\le e^{x-1}$.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered many times. A possible duplicate target was already pointed out. (Your answer is essentially https://math.stackexchange.com/a/504671/42969.)

Comment: The question you mentioned in the comments is not a duplicate of this one unless if $e^x-1=e^{x-1}$. A duplication does not make an answer wrong but if I knew the duplication (though I could guess a bit) I wouldn't have answered it unless through comments...

Comment: The simple substitution $u=x-1$ transforms  $x \le e^{x-1}$ into $u+1 \le e^u$ ....

Comment: Probably it would have been better spending my time to find a duplicate rather than saving that time for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

If i take the ln on both sides we get $$-2\lambda t +2\ln(\lambda)\le -2-2\ln(t)$$ and this is not the result given above!

Comment: Yes, OP applied the square root, not the logarithm. But (1) *is* equivalent to (2).

Comment: Ok, i can read, he/she has written "Applying 
ln
ln
to both sides yields that 
(1)
(1)
should be equivalent to "

Comment: Simply divide by $2$, use $\ln(\lambda t)=\ln\lambda+\ln t$ and apply the exponential function again. Then you obtain $(2)$.