# Deriving the inequality $|\sinh{x}| \le 3|x|, \quad |x| < 1/2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I will like to derive $$|\sinh{x}| \le 3|x|, \quad |x| < 1/2$$

I got this the idea of using this

$$|\exp{x}-1| \le 3|x|, \quad x < 1/2$$

which I found in the appendix. (I admit, that I was looking for something which looked like it).

Q1: The first inequality have the condition $|x| < 1/2$, but the second have $x < 1/2$. I guess that's OK.

Q2: I'm actually not sure if this is the right route I'm taking.

Q3: There is one hint: "use the addition formula". I'm not sure which formula? I think it's this: $$
\sinh (x+y)=\cosh x \sinh y+\sinh x \cosh y
$$

I'm not sure how I will bring this in the play.

NB: Things which are not allowed:
- mean-value theorem

The rule is that I have to use as little theory as possible.

Comment: Q2...Can you tell us what route you’re taking?

Comment: Possibly they mean $\cosh x+\sinh x = e^x$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net
I will like to show |sinhx|≤expx. This is the route

Comment: You even have $|\sinh x<\frac12\mathrm e^x$.

Comment: @Bernard I'm thinking of showing $(\exp(x)/2) \le 3|x|$. I how not seen any inequality which relates these two types of functions.

Comment: If $x\le\frac12$?

Comment: Which inequality do you mean? The inequality in your last comment?

Comment: yes, if x ≤ 1/2

Answer (score 2):

How about using the mean-value theorem? There exists a point $\xi$ in between $x$ and $-x$ satisfying
$$e^x - e^{-x} = e^{\xi}(x - (-x))$$ so that $$\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} = e^\xi x.$$ Take the absolute value to find
$$|\sinh x| \le e^\xi |x|.$$ As long as $|x| \le \log 3$ (which is in fact larger than $1$) you get $|\sinh x| \le 3|x|$.

Comment: Not allowed. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: What is allowed?

Comment: mean-value theorem

Answer (score 2):

A basic inequality is:
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\label{3545836:eq:1}
e^x \geqslant 1 + x,
\end{equation}
which holds for all real $x.$

This has been shown in several previous threads, such as: [Simplest or nicest proof that $1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663).

For what it's worth, my favourite proof of \eqref{3545836:eq:1} is along similar lines to my previous answer to the present question: use the integral definition of the logarithm to prove
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}\label{3545836:eq:2}
\frac{t- 1}t \leqslant \log t \leqslant t - 1 \quad (t > 0),
\end{equation}
distinguishing the cases $t \geqslant 1$ and $t \leqslant 1$
(using both inequalities in \eqref{3545836:eq:2}, we can deduce the case
$t \leqslant 1$ from the case $t \geqslant 1,$ although this isn't necessary),
and then put $t = e^x$ in the second inequality. $\square$

Replacing $x$ by $-2x$ in \eqref{3545836:eq:1}, we get:
$$
1 - e^{-2x} \leqslant 2x
$$
for all real $x,$ and therefore:
$$
\sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}2 = e^x\frac{1 - e^{-2x}}2 \leqslant xe^x \leqslant ex \leqslant 3x \quad (0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\to\dfrac{\sinh x}{x}$ is even and increasing for $x\ge0$, since it's a sum of increasing functions (write de Taylor series).

So all you have to prove is $\sinh (\dfrac12)<\dfrac32$.

But, for $0< x<1$,

$$\sinh x<x+x^3+x^5+\dots=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$

Now let $x=\dfrac12$ in the inequality above.

Comment: Taylor is not allowed :-/

Answer (score 0):

As the functions $\sinh x$ and $3x$ are odd, it is enough to prove it for $0\le x<\frac12$.

Now, simply use that $\sinh x$ is a *convex* function on $[0,+\infty)$. This implies that, on this interval, the graph of the function is below the chord determined by the origin and the point with abscissa $\frac12$,. Explicitly, if $\;0\le x\le\tfrac12$:
$$0\le \sinh x \le \frac{ \sinh\frac12}{\frac12}x=2\sinh\tfrac12 x<\mathrm e^{\tfrac12}x <3x.$$

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if this method is allowed by the question, but it is appealingly geometrical.
We prove:
$$
x < \sinh x < 2x \quad (0 < x \leqslant \log2).
$$

**Proof.** Write $u = e^x,$ so that $1 < u \leqslant 2,$ and
$$
x = \log u = \int_1^u\frac{dt}t.
$$
Thus $x$ is the area of the region $R$ bounded by the graph of $\frac1t,$ the $t$-axis, and the vertical lines $t = 1, t = u$.

This region properly contains the rectangle whose vertices are
$$
(1, 0), \left(1, \frac12\right), (u, 0),  \left(u, \frac12\right),
$$
and whose area is
$$
\frac{u-1}2,
$$
therefore
$$
u - 1 < 2x.
$$

The function $\frac1t$ is convex, so the region $R$ is properly contained in the trapezium $T$ whose vertices are
$$
(1, 0), (1, 1), (u, 0),  \left(u, \frac1u\right),
$$
and whose area is
$$
\frac{u-1}2\left(1 + \frac1u\right) = \frac{u^2 - 1}{2u}
= \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}2 = \sinh x.
$$
But
$$
1 + \frac1u < 2
$$
(more geometrically: the trapezium $T$ is properly contained in the larger rectangle whose vertices are $(1, 0), (1, 1), (u, 0), (u, 1),$ and whose area is $u - 1$), therefore
$$
x < \sinh x < u - 1 < 2x.
$$