# How to prove that $\log(1+x)$ and $1+x^2$ do not intersect?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I tried converting to exponential, $e^{1+x^2} -x -1 = 0$ then finding a contradiction but didn't find one. Then I differentiated to find a minima $> 0$.

i.e solution of $2xe^{1+x^2} -1 = 0$ but didn't find a solution as the term $2xe^{1+x^2}$ doesn't equal to $1$ at any point $x$. Again even if there was any it still would have been a local minima.

Comment: $\log a=\log b \implies a=b$

Answer (score 1):

The derivatives of the two functions are $\frac1{1+x}$ and $2x$. The latter derivative is greater than the former beyond $x_0=0.366\dots$, and we also have $1+x_0^2>\ln(1+x_0)$. This shows that there are no intersections in $[x_0,\infty)$.

In the interval $(-1,x_0]$, $1+x^2\ge1$ but $\ln(1+x)<1$. There are no intersections in this interval either. So the two graphs never intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=1+x^2-\ln(1+x).$

Thus, $$f'(x)=2x-\frac{1}{1+x},$$ which gives $$x_{min}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2}$$ and easy to check that:
$$f\left(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2}\right)>0.%$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^t \ge 1+t$ holds for all real numbers $t$, see for example [Simplest or nicest proof that $1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex).

It follows that
$$
 e^{1+x^2} -x-1 \ge 2+x^2-x-1 = \left(x - \frac 12 \right)^2 + \frac 34 > 0
$$
so that $e^{1+x^2} > 1+x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

An option:

$x>-1;$

Assume the contrary.

$e^{1+x^2}=x+1; $

1)$-1<x \le 0;$

No solution since

$0< RHS \le 1,$ and $LHS >e;$

2)$0<x \le 1;$

LHS$\ge e$, RHS $\le 2;$

3)$x>1;$

LHS: $1+x^2 + T(x^2)$ (expanding),

where $T >0;$

RHS: $1+x;$

LHS > RHS for $x >1.$