# Solve $x - \ln(x) > 1$ without using derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

I would like to solve $x - \ln(x) > 1$ without studying the function $f(x) = x - \ln(x) - 1$ and computing its derivative.

I wonder if solving for $x$ in $x - \ln(x) = 1$ is possible.

It could be possible to consider the Lambert $W$-function, since we can rewrite the expression such that we have

\begin{align*}
  \ln(x) - x   &= 1  \\
  \ln(xe^{-x}) &= 1  \\
  xe^{-x}      &= e  \\
  -xe^{-x}     &= -e
\end{align*}

Yet it seems impossible and non-elementary to have a "nice" analytical solution to this.

Comment: The unique solution is $x=1$....

Comment: It is equivalent to $e^x > 1+x$ for $x \ne 0$, for which many proofs are known: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663/42969.

Comment: What is your definition of the logarithm? What is a “nice analytical proof” without using derivatives?

Comment: $x-ln x=ln e^x-ln x=ln \frac{e^x} x>1= ln e$ , $\rightarrow$, $\frac {e^x}x>e $, which gives: $e^x > e\cdot x$ which is clear for any $x ∈   \mathbb N$ .

Comment: You said you wanted to solve $x - \ln(x) = 1$ (which I think is a good idea) but when you tried to solve it you immediately wrote $\ln(x)-x = 1$, which has no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going on what Martin R said in the comments to the question, using the fact that $\ln(x)$ is defined only for $x>0$ and that $e^x$ is a strictly increasing function,

$x-\ln(x)>1,\ x>0 \implies e^{x-\ln(x)} > e^1,\ x>0 \implies \frac{1}{x}e^x > e,\ x>0 \implies e^x > ex,\ x>0.$

Substituting $x = y+1$ gives:

$e^{y+1} > e(y+1),\ y > -1 \implies e^y> y+1,\ y > -1.$

Various proofs of the final equation for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex). In fact, you only need a proof that works for all $y > -1, $ which other people are welcome to do if they so desire (I'm not going to...).

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a mistake in your solution
\begin{align*}
  x-\ln(x)  &>1  \\
  \ln\left(\frac{e^x}{x}\right) &> 1  \\
  \frac{e^x}{x}    &= e  \\
  e^x    &= xe
\end{align*}
So, it has only one solution which is $x=1.$ I hope that helps