# Prove that $n\ln\left (\dfrac{1+nx}{nx}\right )<1/x$.

Tags: calculus

Let $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x>0$. Prove Prove that $n\ln\left (\dfrac{1+nx}{nx}\right )<1/x$.

**Try:** Trying to play with inequality.
$$\begin{align*}\ln\left (\dfrac{1+nx}{nx}\right )<1/(nx)&\Rightarrow \dfrac{1+nx}{nx}<e^{1/(nx)}\\ &\Rightarrow 1+nx<nx\cdot e^{1/(nx)}
\end{align*}$$
Let $u=nx$, then $1+u<ue^{1/u}$. Any help, after that?

Comment: Let $\;v = \frac{1}{nx} \gt 0\;$ then the inequality reduces to $\;\ln(1+v) \lt v\,$.

Comment: See for example [Simplest or nicest proof that $1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex)

Answer (score 3):

You want to prove $1+u<ue^{\frac{1}{u}}$. To show this it is enough to show that $1+\frac{1}{u}<e^{\frac{1}{u}}$.
Now by  the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ we have

$e^{\frac{1}{u}}=1+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{2!u^2}+\frac{1}{3!u^3}+\cdots>1+\frac{1}{u}$, for $u>0$.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to encounter an inequality about the exponential that cannot be reduced to
$$e^x\ge 1+x\qquad\text{for all }x\in\Bbb R\text{ with equality iff }x=0. $$

Answer (score 1):

Simply , as , $u=nx \gt 0 $ ,$e^{1/u}=1+\frac{1}{1! u}+\frac{1}{2! u^2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot $ is greater than $1+\frac{1}{u}$.

And, hence your conclusion.