# For what $x's$ does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{k^{k^2+2}} x^k$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to try and solve the following problem, as stated in the title:

> For what $x's$ does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{k^{k^2+2}} x^k$ converge?

**Attempt:**

First of all, we try to find the radius of convergence for our given sum. Let $a_k := \frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{k^{k^2+2}}$. The radius of convergence is given by:

$$ R = (\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} |a_k|^{1/k})^{-1}$$

Plugging our value for $a_k$ in the expression above, we have:

$$ R = \left (\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left |\frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{k^{k^2+2}}\right |^{1/k}\right)^{-1}$$

Which can be simplified to:
$$R = \left (\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left |\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k+2/k}}\right |\right)^{-1}$$

Examining the numerator and the denominator separatly, we have that:

$(k+1)^{k} = e^{k\ln(k+1)}$ and $k^{k+2/k} = e^{(k+2/k)\ln(k)}$

Hence:

$$ R = \left (\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left |e^{k\ln(k+1)-(k+2/k)\ln(k)}\right |\right)^{-1}$$

$$ R = \left (\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left |e^{k\ln(1+1/k)-2\ln(k)/k}\right |\right)^{-1}$$

Therefore $R = 1/e$. So, $\forall |x| < 1/e$, we have absolute convergence. Hence, convergence too. We now need to examine the cases $|x| = 1/e$ separately:

**Case $x = 1/e$**

I then have:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{e^k k^{k^2+2}}$.

However, I've a hard time determining on how to show that this is either convergent / divergent, since there're so many complicated factors involved. I'd be glad if you could share any tips on how to proceed with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $x=1/e$, a hint: Write the $k$th term as
$$\left(\frac {k+1}k\right)^{k^2}\frac1{e^kk^2},$$
then apply [the inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663/215011) $1+t\le e^t$ to $\frac{k+1}k$.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I managed to solve it for the negative case too. Really appreciate it :)