# What is this "well-known" inequality called?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am reading an article on q-learning. I don't know what inequality this is, the article says it is well known.

$1- \alpha \leq e^{-\alpha}$

Comment: Use Taylor series for $\text{exp}$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663/42969

Comment: both are converging

Comment: It's closely related to Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: this is certainly true for $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: did the proof writing in a min

Comment: @CameronWilliams you're right

Comment: @abcdefu This is a duplicate. Close it instead of answer it.

Comment: @azif00 oh...thanks for telling

Comment: Yes, thanks @abcdefu