# $\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$, in $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2| x\in[0,3]\}$

Tags: inequality

I have tried to use convexity properties because I have checked their graphs from (desmos.com) and it was appropriate to try but I am very ignorant to do convexity in two variable so I have tried to look at their differentials.

$$d(e^{x+y-2})=e^{x+y-2}dx+e^{x+y-2}dy$$
$$d\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}\right)=x/2 dx+ y/2 dy$$

I might say that for a fixed $y=y_0$, $e^{x+y-2}dx$ exceed $x/2 dx$ and similarly for $y$ one.

No method comes to my mind, I saw this somewhere and tried to solve but couldnot. Any help, hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $0\leq y \leq 3$ also? For x=0,y=-1 the inequality fails

Comment: the original was as I wrote but you are right, I guess I should delete the question.

Comment: Delete the question ? Not necessarily ... You said you have checked with Desmos : what have you checked ?

Comment: It is correct for $x, y \ge 0$: [Show that $\forall (x,y)$ in the first quadrant: $\frac {x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286695/show-that-forall-x-y-in-the-first-quadrant-frac-x2y24-leq-exy)

Comment: @Jean Marie.  like convexitywise x^2 and x^3 in (0,1)  x^2 as exp one is bigger